# Why is $\frac{10x\Delta x +5( \Delta x)^2}{\Delta x}=10x+ 5\Delta x$? (Algebra error)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How is $\frac{10x\Delta x +5( \Delta x)^2}{\Delta x}=10x+ 5\Delta x$, and not $10x\Delta x+5\Delta x$, or $10x+5(\Delta x)^2$? What am I missing here? (Even though this may be an algebraic error, perhaps I should know why if I understood the change of x correctly?)

Comment: It seems like you are just simplifying $\Delta x$...

Comment: For the same reason why for example $\,(3 \cdot 2 + 5 \cdot 2^2) / 2 = 3 + 5 \cdot 2\,$ and not something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what your confusion is about, but it seems that if you factor out $\Delta x$ in the numerator, you have

$$
\frac{10x\Delta x + 5 (\Delta x)^2}{\Delta x} =
\frac{\Delta x(10x + 5\Delta x)}{\Delta x} =
10x + 5\Delta x
$$

Comment: We can't cross out without factoring it first?

Comment: @ReducedGosling It sounds like you think that $$\frac{a+bc}c=a+b$$ is that right?

Comment: When you "cross out without factoring", you essentially do the factoring in your mind without writing it down. The term that you are crossing out has to be a factor, so the factoring is necessary.

Comment: @ReducedGosling $$\frac{A+B}C=\frac AC+\frac BC$$ so $$\frac{10x\Delta x+5(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta x}=\frac{10x\Delta x}{\Delta x}+\frac{5(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta x}=10x+5\Delta x$$

Comment: @bof Yes, exactly! That should be the accepted answer. Also Matti P's comment helped a lot.